# Can't removeEventListener inside a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can't removeEventListener in this function for some reason. Can someone help me please? I know I've made a mistake somewhere in the code, but I don't know where.

```
  let f = false;
document.querySelector('.nav_button').addEventListener('click', function foo() {
  if (f) {
    document.querySelector('.nav_button').style = "margin-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;"
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('.nav_button').removeEventListener('click', foo);
    }, 2000);
  }
  f = !f;
})
```

Comment: How do you know that the event handler is not removed?

Comment: What is the `f` variable?

Comment: I thought my button will go back at it's place after I removeEventListerner...So, I did remove eventlistener but the besides that nothing will happen right? @heretic-monkey

Comment: @nomorekane - it sounds to me like you want to reset the style after 2 seconds, not remove the event handler.

Comment: You are correct @Adam :))

Comment: Removing the event listener works fine as you can see in this fiddle. Logs will not occur after 2 seconds after the first click. https://jsfiddle.net/jtysm049/

Comment: Not sure why you're tagging me, I just edited your post to add a space after the period, because that's how English works. But yes, removing the event listener does nothing but remove event listener; it does not "reverse" what the original event listener does. That would be extremely difficult to do. What if an event handler makes a POST to a REST API to save something to a database? How would the browser know how to reverse that?

Answer (score 1):

Removing an event listener won't magically undo the changes made by that event listener. There are also some significant issues with your code in general, notably repetition, hard-coding stuff, and mixing of JS and CSS that should be avoided.

Here's a rewrite of your code using somewhat better practices:

```js
// JS:
const button = document.querySelector(".nav_button");
button.addEventListener("click", e=>button.classList.toggle("opened"), false);
```

```css
/* CSS: */
.nav_button.opened {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

---

If you want to delay the button returning to its default position, you can do so:

```css
.nav_button {
    /* give some defaults here */
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;

    /* this is where the magic happens */
    transition-property: margin-top, font-size;
    transition-duration: 0s;
    /* this defines the delay of *returning to* this state */
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.nav_button.opened {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* no delay when transitioning TO this state */
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: Further improvements could be made by making it an `<input type="checkbox" />` and styling based on `.nav_button:checked` instead, removing the need for JS entirely.

Comment: The OP wants to remove that clas after 2 seconds, don't forget.

Comment: @Adam Thanks - edited post to add a delay option.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah, for some reason in my head I thought its gonna magically happen. Beginners... xd

Comment: But this isn't what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of what you wanted: change styling after a click, then, after 2 seconds, remove the styling that was added.

```
var to; // a reference to a timer
var button = document.querySelector('.nav_button')
button.addEventListener('click', () {
 // every time the button is clicked add a class and clear the timer
 clearInterval(to); 
 button.classList.add('opened');

 // two seconds after the last click, remove the class
 to = setTimeout(() => button.classList.remove('opened'),2000);
})
```

CSS:

```
.nav_button.opened {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, your code looks so smooth:)Gonna use it for sure

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use below code.

```
document.querySelector('.nav_button').addEventListener('click', foo)
    function foo() {
        if (f) {
            document.querySelector('.nav_button').style = "margin-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;"

        } else {
            document.querySelector('.nav_button').removeEventListener('click', foo);
        }
        f = !f;
    }
```

```js
var f = true;
    document.querySelector('.nav_button').addEventListener('click', foo)
    function foo() {
        if (f) {
            document.querySelector('.nav_button').style = "margin-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;"

        } else {
            document.querySelector('.nav_button').removeEventListener('click', foo);
        }
        f = !f;
    }
```

```html
    <button class="nav_button">test</button>
```